# static website on s3 gives 404 on refresh for non home page: no such keys error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

On clicking/refresh following site https://rrc6k2ykxxxxx.cloudfront.net/example-1

this error comes for all non home page url
I have reactjs App on s3 bucket which is served through cloudfront.

Error:
NoSuchKey
The specified key does not exist.
Key: example-1

what would be best way to redirect refresh on non home pages back to home page?  thanks

Answer (score 9):

Assuming this is a single page app (SPA) since this is react - in other words, there is no file in your s3 bucket `example-1/index.html`?

For single-page apps, whatever is delivering the static contents needs to return the root `index.html` file for all unmatched paths. In CloudFront, you can click on the distribution, then click on "Error pages", click "Create a custom error response", select 404 for the HTTP error code, select "create a custom error response" and put `/index.html` in the response page path with a 200 for the response code. You will want to repeat this for a 403 error code.

Comment: Thanks, had to edit cloudfront and that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Just set the Error Page to index.html it will solve the problem. *path =>* Go to aws s3 then in buckets select properties tab and go to  **Static website hosting**
[Static website hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXBvj.png)